# Google Adsense не принимает мой сайт по причине "Insufficient content"

Tags: google-adsense

Почему [мой сайт](http://www.999stories.com/) не утверждает Google Adsense? 
Вот ответ Google после рассмотрения моего сайта:

> "Insufficient content: To be approved for AdSense and show relevant
>   ads on your site, your pages need to have enough text on them for our
>   specialists to review and for our crawler to be able to determine what
>   your pages are about."

Comment: Вы смогли перевести текст ответа?

Comment: Идем в гугл-переводчик и смотрим на переведенный текст: "Недостаточно содержания. Чтобы одобрить AdSense и показать релевантные объявления на вашем сайте, ваши страницы должны иметь достаточно текста на них, чтобы наши специалисты могли их просмотреть, и чтобы наш поисковый робот мог определить, о чем ваши страницы." :)